# How to call AsyncRelayCommand

Tags: c#, mvvm, lambda, async-await

I have a WPF MVVM application, created with VS2015.

I have been using a "RelayCommand" class to wire up command calls from the xaml to the view model. This has worked well but now I have a button click that triggers a process that takes a long time. I'd like to make this Async so that the UI remains responsive.

I've updated my view model method to make it, and all downstream calls async. This is now working well from my unit test, which I also updated to make the async reequest.

I found an AsyncRelayCommand class which implements ICommand and has the following constructor:

```
public AsyncRelayCommand(Func<object, Task> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        this.execute = execute;
        this.canExecute = canExecute ?? (o => true);
    }
```

My problem is, I don't know how to create an instance of the AsyncRelayCommand. I have tried the following:

```
CompareCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(Task.Run(() => OnCompareAsync));
```

This gives the red sqiggly under the "OnCompareAsync" with 3 errors, including:

> Cannot convert method group 'OnCompareAsync' to non-delegate type 'Task'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

How do I use this constructor?

Comment: Which `AsyncRelayCommand` are you using? Because [this one](https://github.com/rsuter/MyToolkit/wiki/AsyncRelayCommand) has an example. BTW, what you are doing there is passing an (almost certainly) incomplete `Task` to the constructor because that is what `Task.Run()` returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the MyToolkit nuget package suggested by Crowcoder. I was then able to get a compile with "CompareCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(OnCompareAsync);"

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
CompareCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(async (o) => await OnCompareAsync());
```

Comment: That gives the errors: 1) Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' 2) Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

Comment: @RobBowman Updated.  I assume you have "public async Task OnCompareAsync(){...}" and the purpose of the lambda is to add an "object" parameter which you do not need/have in your OnCompareAsync.